# changing the difinition of inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{R}$ and $V \neq\{0\}$. Replace the
>   positivity condition (which states that $\langle v,v\rangle \geq 0
>  \forall v \in V $ in the definition of an inner product with the
>   condition that $ \exists  v \in V ,\langle v,v\rangle > 0 $.
>
> Show that this change in the definition does not change the set of
>   functions from $V \times V \to \mathcal{R}$ that are inner products on
>   $V$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Arthur, "What have you tried?" - 

What an annoying question!

Comment: It looks like there are some typos in which case it'd be good to clean the text of the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem means that, in the following four conditions that define an inner product on a vector space $V \neq {0}$ over $\mathbb{R}$:

1. Positivity:$\langle v, v \rangle \ge 0$ for all $v\in V$,
2. Definiteness: $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$,
3. Additivity in first slot: $\langle u+v, w \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$ for all $u,v,w \in V$,
4. Homogeneity in first slot: $\langle \lambda v, w \rangle = \lambda \langle v,w \rangle$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb(R)$ and $v,w \in V$,

even if we replace 1 by the following weaker condition

5. $\langle v, v \rangle > 0$ for some $v\in V$
   we still get 1. In other words, conditions 2,3,4, and 5 imply 1.

To prove it, suppose that there is also some $w \in V$ such that $\langle w, w \rangle <0$. It is easy to see that $w$ is not a multiple of $v$. Now for each $t \in [0,1]$, we define $u(t) = tv + (1-t)w$. Then $$\langle u(t), u(t) \rangle = t^{2}\langle v, v \rangle + (1-t)^{2} \langle w, w \rangle + 2t(1-t)\langle v, w \rangle$$ This is a polynomial with $\langle u(0), u(0) \rangle <0$ and $\langle u(1), u(1) \rangle >0$. Hence there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that $\langle u(t), u(t) \rangle = 0$, which, by condition 2, implies that $tv + (1-t)w = 0$, or $w$ is a multiple of $v$, a contradiction.

(This is not my proof, I saw it on Raddit somewhere. I hope it can help you.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly then it is false. Define $\langle (x,y) , (x',y') \rangle =xx'$ on $\mathbb R^{2}$. This is not an inner product in the usual sense but $\langle v , v \rangle >0$ when $v=(1,1)$.